# Javascript - Onclick toggle between image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, image-size

I have multiple images, say image A, image B and image C. When I click image A I want it to enlarge. When I then click on image B I want image A to revert back to its original size and B to enlarge.

Here is the codepen im working off: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWXrEv

Help would be much appreciated.

Html Code:

```
<img class="image" src="http://images.e-flux- 
systems.com/646a999d89943180a9b4916b17fd7bac.jpg,2000" alt="" />

<img class="image" src="http://images.e-flux- 
systems.com/2012_09_01the_internet.jpg,1440" alt="" />
```

Css:

```
.image {
 width: 150px;
}

.image.enlarge {
 width: 600px;;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('enlarge');
   });
  });
```

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a quick fix is to remove the `.enlarge` class from all images before adding the class to another image. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.image').click(function() {
    $('.image').removeClass('enlarge');
    $(this).addClass('enlarge');
   });
  });
```

Hopefully this works!

Also, you have an extra semicolon in your CSS, so watch out for that!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the existing `.enlarge` class from all of the existing element where class name is `.image` if any and add the `.enlarge` class **only** on the current clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image').click(function() {
    $(".image").removeClass('enlarge');
    $(this).toggleClass('enlarge');
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 150px;
}

.image.enlarge {
  width: 600px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="http://images.e-flux-systems.com/646a999d89943180a9b4916b17fd7bac.jpg,2000" alt="" />

<img class="image" src="http://images.e-flux-systems.com/2012_09_01the_internet.jpg,1440" alt="" />
```